# Can P vs NP be independent of accepted axioms?

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np

On [wikipedia's page on P vs NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) it says that think that of 151 researchers surveyed, their thoughts were as follows:

> "126 (83%) believed the answer to be no, 12 (9%) believed the answer
>   is yes, 5 (3%) believed the question may be independent of the
>   currently accepted axioms and therefore is impossible to prove or
>   disprove, 8 (5%) said either don't know or don't care or don't want
>   the answer to be yes nor the problem to be resolved."

But can't P vs NP be restated as "Is there a polynomial time algorithm for 3SAT?", since $P=NP$ if there is and $P\neq NP$ if there is not.

It seems like this restatement cannot be independent of the axioms, if it were there would be some spaces where there IS a P time algorithm, and some where there isn't, with both being consistent with the regular axioms -- however couldn't one just use any P-time algorithm in that former group, since it must be consistent with our axioms?

Is there some subtlety that I am missing?

Any recommendations for books/textbooks/further readings that cover P vs NP and related problems in detail?

Comment: "Independent of the axioms" means that it can't be proven from those axioms. So, in your reformulation in terms of 3SAT, it would mean that there is no algorithm that can be proven to run in polynomial time and proven to solve 3SAT. It's still possible that there is a polytime algorithm for 3SAT; it's just that, from those particular axioms, either it's impossible to prove that it runs in polytime, or impossible to prove that it solves 3SAT or both.

Comment: I saw the other post before posting, I was more curious about whether a specific problem would necessarily have a P time algorithm or not. I see what you are saying, and I can think of an intuition for examples for both, thanks.